# How kafka fetch data only when new row insert or update old row from mysql database using kafka streaming

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent platform JDBC connector, it is streaming data from mysql to kafka consumer. Through an application inserting data into another database for reporting purpose.
Here problem it is only streaming all data again and again within some interval of time. Actually a want only those data which is newly inserted or any update of previous record.

According to timestamp can't do because table does not contain any time column. And as per increment id also not possible. Please share any solution.

I have sample configuration file.

```
demo.json
{
    "name":"mysql-connector-demo",
    "config":{
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
                "connection.user": "root",
                "connection.password": "1234",
                "topic.prefix": "test",
                "catalog.pattern":"test",
                "mode": "bulk",
                "validate.non.null": false,
                "query": "select * from test ",
                "table.types": "TABLE",
                "topic.prefix": "test-jdbc-",
                "poll.interval.ms": 10000
                "schema.ignore": true,
                "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
                "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

But here new inserted record and newly updated record not affected to kafka consumer.

Answer (score 0):

> want only those data which is newly inserted or any update of previous record

Then you should be using change-data-capture (CDC) rather than JDBC polling.

Debezium is one such solution

Comment: For Debezium need to change the configuration file specially binlog-format = ROW. But i am using master and replica structure of mysql, it has already binlog-format = MIXED for all machines. Debzium does not allow MIXED format and can not change because master and all replica already configure with MIXED only.

Comment: Alright, well, the JDBC connector grabs entire rows, not subsets of what you're interested in, and the bulk config mode will read the entire table continuously, as stated in the documentation. Maybe you should add a lastUpdated column that you can add to every row that defaults to the current time